# Glyphicons elevating with each one added

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have added 3 glpyhs inside my h3 tag and have applied a style to it however every glyph I add they seem to be moving upwards so they are not in line with each other like this [(check link for picture)](http://gyazo.com/ddd22aa8a71adc64118016f4626f4caf)

This is how I have added the glyphs within the panel.

```
<div class="col-md-4 column">
    <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-backcolour">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons" /><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons" /></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            Panel content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the custom css that I am applying to the panel.

```
.panel-icons{
float: right;
cursor:pointer;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to close your `span` tags.

Also I should point out, span is not a [self closing](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html) tag, as you have tried to make use of it.

```css
.panel-icons {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-md-4 column">
  <div class="panel panel-default" draggable="true">
    <div class="panel-heading panel-backcolour">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
          </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      Panel content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give your answer a tick when it lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Correct your markup to have the `span` properly close like so:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash panel-icons"></span>
```

As your code is now, it thinks that each glyphicon is within the previous glyphicon and you haven't properly closed your `span` tag.

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/sfrisk/pen/6f47049e3187cd6c4d8f7ca3cd838b7c) link for a working example.